# Does the enemy get experience when Enigma creates Eidelons from his own team's creep?

Tags: dota-2, dota

And if so, how much - it is a normal deny or a complete, zero-experience-to the-enemy deny?

Comment: I thought ranged/melee deny xp depends on what the enemy hero was, not whether or not the denying hero was ranged/melee?

Comment: I just checked playdota.com and you're right.  Wow.  Evidently I've been misunderstanding that mechanic for years.

Just corrected my original post to make more sense - thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero experience to opponents, even if they're within range.

Comment: Basically this. [It wasn't always this way though (speaking on DotA 2 specifically though)](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/July_01,_2011_Patch#HEROES):
 Lich - Units sacrificed via Dark Ritual won't give deny XP to enemies.

Comment: Please take note that a recent patch has changed lich's deny mechanic. It now Grants XP to enemies